# how to handle duplicate file(.txt and .txt~) after save file with emacs

Tags: emacs, backup

Sorry, I have a problem when I try to learn emacs in terminal, when I try to edit 1 file (file.txt) and I try to save this file with C-x C-s. I get 2 files with the same name (file.txt and file. txt~). how to handle duplicate file after save file with emacs on mac osx?

Comment: Does `handle` mean that you don't want to create backup-files automatically?  See the write-up by Xah Lee:  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_set_backup_into_a_directory.html

Comment: If you don't want emacs to create backup files, you can [disable that functionality](http://superuser.com/questions/84164/how-do-i-stop-emacs-from-creating-backup-files).

Comment: But of course *disabling backups* would generally be very silly. Just make Emacs put them somewhere that won't bother you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~`-suffixed file is a backup copy of the file, with the state it had before you started editing.

- You can [disable](https://superuser.com/a/84168/250462) such automatic backing up.
- You can also control various aspects of such backing up, including where backup files are to be stored -- see the Emacs manual, node [Backup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html) and its subnodes.
- You can also remove all of the backup files in a directory at once, by visiting the directory using Dired: `C-x d`. After visiting it, use `~` to mark all backup files for deletion, then `x` to delete them. See the Emacs manual, node [Flagging Many Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Flagging-Many-Files.html).

Comment: Hi Drew, Thanks for your answer. that's very helpful. thanks

Comment: Why are backups persistent even after saving the file and closing Emacs?

Comment: @user7778287: Why wouldn't they be? You decide whether to create backups. You decide whether and when to delete them.

Comment: Because the obvious use case is recovery after Emacs crashes. Storing a backup in the same folder isn't much assurance for any other accidents - obviously the default behavior  can be changed.